How does a stirring beam generate a vortex state in BEC?
I am studying BEC and I have a small problem of understanding vortex issue in the BEC. From the paper by Eric Cornell: Vortices in a Bose-Einstein Condensate. They use a rotating blue detuned laser to generate a vortex state in one of the internal states of Rubidium-87 (in the article they denoted as $|2\rangle$).
My thought is that they use this rotating beam to drag $|2\rangle$ in the BEC rotating with the laser.
However, they said in order to create a vortex in $|2\rangle$, 780 nm laser beam that has a waist of 180 μm and is detuned 0.8 GHz blue of resonant excitation of the $|2\rangle$ state. Using piezoelectric actuators we rotate the beam in a ∼75 μm radius circle around the condensate at 100Hz.
This 780nm laser is used for Rubidium D2 transition.

I don't think it works because the AC Stark shift produced by the blue detuned rotating light provides a peak for $|2\rangle$ rather than a valley, so those $|2\rangle$ won't be dragged by the rotating laser light.


( I suppose they used Gaussian beam.)
However it works, that is my most confused part. I don't know what information I am lack of.
